# What is the correct W3C Click event specification?

Tags: javascript, html, webkit, w3c, qtwebkit

Is it normal that in Firefox or a previous version of QTWebkit a click event is not fired in these cases:

- mousedown on element > mouseup on child element >>> NO CLICK triggered
- mousedown on child element > mouseup on parent element >>> NO CLICK triggered

http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-click
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=326851

Test URL: http://jsfiddle.net/3d6dzr02/

```js
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click",function(){
  alert("ok");
})
```

```css
div {
  padding:20px;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <div style="margin:20px; background:yellow;">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Works well on last chrome version

I don't know if chrome is OK or if it is Firefox that do correctly the spec.
So should it trigger event or not?

Comment: Two different browsers, two different ways of doing things. One is not more right from the other.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, Firefox behaves differently from IE and Chrome, which fire a 'click' on the common ancestor(?) when `mousedown` and `mouseup` happen on different elements. The votes from the browser vendors are:

- [Mozilla bug 1229143](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1229143) ("Not receiving click event on the common ancestor of two elements") - no decision made
- <s>[Chrome issue 484655](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=484655)</s> merged into [543776](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=543776) ("Stop sending "click" on mouse drag across elements") - doesn't intend to change their behavior.
- [<s>IE bug 809003</s>](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/809003/unexpected-click-event-triggered-when-the-elements-below-cursor-at-mousedown-and-mouseup-events-are-different) moved to [Edge issue #103724](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/103724/) ("Unexpected Click event triggered when the elements below cursor at mousedown and mouseup events are different") - marked as fixed without any comments (I didn't test if it indeed is)

I think even the latest version of the spec (now called [The UI Events](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#event-type-click)) is unclear about this:

> The click event type MUST be dispatched on the topmost event target indicated by the pointer, when the user presses down and releases the primary pointer button [...]

You could argue that this implies that the "topmost event target indicated by the pointer" is the same for the mousedown and the mouseup, but it's not clear.

Later in an example there's this text:

> trigger a click event [..], since the user has stayed within the scope of the same element.

...which supports the hypothesis that the intention of the spec authors aligned with what was implemented in Firefox.